# How to fill the ListView from another class correctly in Android?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

My android-app gets List in the one activity, but activity,that contains the LisView for this list is in another class. so:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<CityInfo> result) 
{

    CityArrayDataAdapter cityArrayDataAdapter = new CityArrayDataAdapter(CityParserActivity.this, listCitiesData);  
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

where CityParserActivity.this is context of my another activity. But Eclipse shows me the next:

*No enclosing instance of the type CityParserActivity is accessible in scope*

How to fix this problem? Thanks for help.

Possible fix:

```
CityParserActivity cityParserActivity = new CityParserActivity();
CityArrayDataAdapter cityArrayDataAdapter = new CityArrayDataAdapter(cityParserActivity, listCitiesData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you expecting to get your instance of `CityParserActivity`? Are you passing a reference to that somewhere into your enclosing class of this `AsyncTask`? You can't "wish" a `CityParserActivity` into existence by trying to cast your `this` pointer into one if you're not *currently* in your `CityParserActivity`.

Comment: Sure, I can't wish, you right. So, should I do the AsyncTask the inner class for my activity?
Or do so, as I updated post, if I understood your words correctly?

Comment: Either that -- which, yes, would resolve the `CityParserActivity.this` thing correctly -- or pass a reference to your `CityParserActivity` into whatever class _does_ host the `AsyncTask` so it can be referenced.

Comment: I wouldn't like to do it so, becouse of another activities share this activity between their.

Comment: You know your code, I don't. If you need a reference to something, find the best way to acquire that reference in your design. Whether that's changing where it lives or providing a method to set the reference. You asked why you were getting that message and how to fix it and this is the way. You need that reference. So get the reference.